# Cleared git cache, broke site

Tags: git, caching, github, git-commit

There are a couple of things to know up front:

1. I'm putting together a super simple site [here](https://github.com/cmegown/cmegown.github.io).
2. I know next to nothing about Git, so I use the GitHub for Windows app.

After a couple of successful commits yesterday I started to receive an error every time I tried to create a new one "Unable to create commit". After some research it appeared to not add new files, so I figured it had something to do with caching. I did some quick searching and gave this a shot:

```
git rm -r --cached
git commit -am 'git cache cleared'
git push
```

Things still work fine locally, but [the prod site](http://www.coreymegown.com/) can no longer find the styles.css file (404). Any ideas? If so, please provide some description around it so that I can understand what went wrong and why.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The issue to the site not building was actually because I had directories that started with underscores, which is prohibited because of the native support for Jekyll. Adding a `.nojekyll` file to the root of the repo solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Git "cache" has nothing to do with web caching, or probably what you would normally think of as a cache in other programs. In general, this would refer to the *staging area*, which is used when determining what should be committed. In the case of `git rm` it doesn't really mean that either, at least as far as I can see.

When you `git rm --cached` something, you remove it from the Git repository, but leave it in your working copy. This means that your local copy, where you ran the command, still has the files. But when you pushed that new commit, the copies of all the files you removed were deleted from the other copy!

You should probably `revert` that commit, which will actually create a *new* commit that undoes the problematic one. If this was your most recent commit, do this:

```
git revert -n HEAD^
git commit -am "Replace accidentally deleted files"
git push
```

If it was an earlier commit, look through the log (using `git log` or the graphical GitHub app) to find its hash. Then replace `HEAD^` with the commit hash (the first seven characters should be enough).

Once that is done, you need to determine the cause of your original problem. If the graphical GitHub isn't able to give you a useful error message, try committing on the command line to see if that gives more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris! I'll try some stuff out and see what works, then report back.

Comment: I had to revert back to an earlier commit, which seemed to solve some of the weird issues I was seeing. So thank you for that! However, the entire problem was actually caused by something else entirely (see edit to original question).

Comment: @cmegown, I'm glad you found a solution.